# How to install xsd via VSIX installer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vsix, xml-editor

Visual Studio uses xsd files to provide intellisense for xml files that matches the namespace. I have created custom xml schema and I want to apply that schema when user is editing that type of document containing my namespace. I can manually keep my xsd somewhere and I can get intellisense correctly. But I want to deploy this schema along with VSIX installer so that it is applied automatically.

I need to setup this with VSIX, I know which folder to install to, but I am new to VSIX and if there is a way I can install Content "XSD" to specific folder I am done.

Comment: Do you need to know in which location to install the xsd? Or do you need help setting this up with VSIX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, deployment of XSD's via VSIX is not supported in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Do you know if this is still true of newer Visual Studios?

Comment: Starting with Visual Studio 2017 you can install XSD to the Visual Studio Schema folder. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/set-install-root